# sequence question again - i think my book is wrong

Tags: analysis

So here it says:

if a sequence $a(n)\rightarrow a\neq0$ then $a\cdot a(n)>\frac{a^2}{2}$ for every natural $n$

But that implies that if the limit is $2$ for example, then every term in that sequence is positive.

I understand the proof of this about i dont think it applies for every $n$ but every $n\geq N$ so that $|a(n)-a|<\frac{|a|}{2}$ if we choose that $\varepsilon$ (I chose that because he did)

Consider this sequence: $a(n)= \dfrac{\ln(\frac{n-8}{10})}{n} +1$ . The limit is positive but $a(1)$ is negative. Am i wrong about sth? pls explain

Comment: i could take a photo but its in greek -_- it clearly says for every natural n, though

Answer (score 2):

It should say for every natural $n$ greater than some $N$.  You are correct that it could fail for some finite (even very large) number of $n$, but must stop eventually.

Comment: yes ofc it must stop since the limit is positive for example, thank u, i finally got sth right :D